# How to unnest json data to dataframe using python

Tags: python, json, pandas, unnest

import json
import pandas as pd

```
resp = requests.get('https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/query/77hc-ibv8/0?offset=0&count=true&results=true&schema=true&keys=true&format=json')
data = resp.json()
data = json.dumps(resp_dict,indent=4)
print(data)
```

I am trying to unnest the json data into a dataframe using Python. There are a few ways to do it but wasn't able to fully unnest the json data. What would be the best way to accomplish this?[image]

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe; also share the code you tried that worked/failed?

Comment: What's nested? Do you mean the results? `pd.DataFrame(data['results'])` will make the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special just pass it to pd.DataFrame and refer to the main key.

```
import json

import pandas as pd

import requests


def get_data() -> pd.DataFrame:
    url = (
        "https://data.cms.gov/provider-data/api/1/datastore/query/77hc-ibv8/0?"
        "offset=0&"
        "count=true&"
        "results=true&"
        "schema=true&"
        "keys=true&"
        "format=json"
    )

    with requests.Session() as request:
        response = request.get(url, timeout=10)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(response.raise_for_status())

    data = json.loads(response.text)

    return pd.DataFrame(data=data["results"])


print(get_data())
```

Comment: Hi Jason, running this script returns the first 500 rows. Is there a way to return the entire rows? thanks alot!